# Existence of homomorphism in diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Consider the following diagram where each complex is an $R-$module and the rows are **exact** and the maps $g,h$ are $R-$mod homomoprhisms and the right square commmutes $h(p(b)) = q(g(b)), \forall b \in B$. Then there is in fact a nontrivial $R-$mod homomorphism $f: A \to A'$ that makes the left square commute and if $g,h$ are isomorphisms, so is $f$.

\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & \xrightarrow{} & A & \xrightarrow{i} & B & \xrightarrow{p} & C \\
\downarrow &  & \downarrow & & \downarrow{g} &  &\downarrow {h}  \\
0 & \xrightarrow{} & A' & \xrightarrow{j} & B' & \xrightarrow{q} & C' 
\end{array}

So I see $i,j$ are injective by exactness, but I don't see how the other maps come into play. How do we show existence of homomorphisms in general?

Comment: The statement should be that $f$ makes the left square commute, not that it is nontrivial (it might be trivial; after all, $A$ and/or $A'$ might be $0$).

Comment: *nontrivial complexes - used suggested edit nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to define $f:A\to A'$.  So take an element $x\in A$, and let's figure out what $f(x)$ needs to be.  For the diagram to commute, we must have $j(f(x))=g(i(x))$.  So let's define $f(x)$ to be the unique element $y\in A'$ such that $j(y)=g(i(x))$, if such an element exists (there is at most one such $y$ by injectivity of $j$).  To show such an element exists, we need to show $g(i(x))$ is in the image of $j$, which is the same as the kernel of $q$.  That is, we want $q(g(i(x)))=0$.  But $qg=hp$, so $q(g(i(x)))=h(p(i(x)))$, which is $0$ since $pi=0$.

So $g(i(x))$ is always in the image of $j$, so we really can define $f(x)$ in this way.  It is now straightforward to check that $f(x)$ is a homomorphism: it is the composition of $i$, $g$, and $j^{-1}$ (this last map being defined only on the image of $j$), which are all homomorphisms.

Comment: Um, this is gonna sound silly, but *why* do we want the diagrams to commute? I don't see what the info about the right square commutating has to do with anything. *I mean what is the importantance of commutating.

Comment: Oh, that should be part of the statement.  Otherwise it would be silly; you could just define $f=0$.

Comment: and it would be an isomoprhism because it is the composition of a 2 injective and one isomorphic map right?

Comment: When $g$ is injective, you can deduce that $f$ is injective in that way.  To show that $f$ is surjective requires more work, but is fairly straightforward if you follow your nose.